# Merging 2 arrays with different size by the same value of their keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

Can I merge 2 arrays with the same value of the same key? Already tried using map.set() but it wont work on my end.

```
const errArray = [
 { 'id': 1, 'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"] }
 { 'id': 2, 'error': ["Error 3", "Error4"] }
]

const warnArray = [
 { 'id': 1, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]}
]
```

I want to have a result of :

```
[
 { 'id': 1, 
   'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"],
   'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]
 }, {
   'id': 2,
   'error': ["Error 3", "Error4]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You first `concat` them into one array. Then group by `id`, extending into each other those who match by `id`.
Then finally flatten the object into array.

```js
const errArray = [{
    'id': 1,
    'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"]
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'error': ["Error 3", "Error4"]
  }
]

const warnArray = [{
  'id': 1,
  'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]
}]

var combined = errArray.concat(warnArray)


var result = Object.values(combined.reduce(function(agg, value) {
  agg[value.id] = Object.assign({}, value, agg[value.id]);
  return agg;
}, {}));


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is this possible as well? ***[
 { 'id': 1, 
   'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"],
   'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]
 }, {
   'id': 2,
   'error': ["Error 3", "Error4], 'warning':[]
 }
]***

Comment: yes instead of `Object.assign` to an empty one `{}` , do it for `{error:[], warning:[]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of unique `id` by mapping each array to its `id` and creating a spread `Set` of them with  `[...new Set(Array)]`. Then you can `map` each key to a combined object with `Object.assign()` and `array.find()`:

```js
const errArray = [
  { 'id': 1, 'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"] },
  { 'id': 2, 'error': ["Error 3", "Error4"] }
 ]
 
 const warnArray = [
  { 'id': 1, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]}
 ]

const keys = [
  ...new Set([
    ...errArray.map((v) => v.id), // [1, 2]
    ...warnArray.map((v) => v.id) // [1]
  ]),
];   //  keys = [1, 2]

const combined = keys.map((key) =>
  Object.assign({},
    errArray.find((v) => v.id === key),
    warnArray.find((v) => v.id === key)
  )
);

console.log(combined)
```

Comment: Is it possible for the id:2 to add warning as an empty array??

Comment: No, it won't do that, `Object.assign()` will merge the objects that `find()` returns. With no `id:2` in `warnArray`, `find()` will return `undefined`, and `Object.assign()` won't  use it as a source. It'll be fine. [Here is an example](https://jsbin.com/bavenez/edit?js,console) with `id:5` in `warnArray` and `id:6` in `errArray`, the output should be what you expect.

Comment: @monami But is that the behavior you want it to do? If that's the case, that can be solved without much extra code.

Comment: @monami [Here](https://jsbin.com/bavenez/edit?js,console) is a version that adds an empty array for wranings or errors that don't have a counterpart in the other array. It uses parenthesis that evaluate with an  OR `||` to return a default empty object, if it doesn't find the ID in the array. so if `let obj = (array.find() || defaultObj)` and it doesnt `find()` cant find it in the array then `obj = (udefined || defaultObj)` and then `obj === defaultObj`

Answer (score 0):

```
const errArray = [
    { 'id': 1, 'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"] },
    { 'id': 2, 'error': ["Error 3", "Error4"] }]

const warnArray = [
    { 'id': 1, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]},
    { 'id': 2, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]},
    { 'id': 3, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]}
]

let merged = []

if(errArray.length > warnArray.length){
    merged = errArray.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, warnArray[i]));
}
else{
    merged = warnArray.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, errArray[i]));
}

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation using the map:

```js
const errArray = [
 { 'id': 1, 'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"] },
 { 'id': 2, 'error': ["Error 3", "Error4"] }
]

const warnArray = [
 { 'id': 1, 'warning': ["Error 5", "Error6"]}
]

const myMap = new Map();
errArray.forEach(err => {
    myMap.set(err.id, err);
});


warnArray.forEach(warn => {
    if(!myMap.has(warn.id)) {
        myMap.set(warn.id, warn);
    }
    else {
// You might want to do better merging than this, if the objects are complex
        const mergedObj = Object.assign({}, myMap.get(warn.id), warn);
        myMap.set(warn.id, mergedObj)
    }
});

const resultArr = Array.from(myMap.values());

console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end

```
const err = [{ 
    'id': 1, 
    'error': ["Error 1", "Error2"]
}]

const warn = [{ 
    'id': 1, 
    'warning': ["Warn 1", "Warn 2"]
}]

const map = new Map();

err.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item));

warn.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, {...map.get(item.id), ...item}));

const combined = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(combined)
```